# Kinetic mixing, and a bare mass?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, photons, renormalization, regularization, self-energy

I've been reading the following classic paper by Bob Holdom ["Two $U(1)$s and $\epsilon$ charge shifts"](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(86)91377-8), and I'm attempting to derive the expression for $\chi$. In particular, I am computing the following one-loop vacuum polarization diagram

$$
\Pi_{12}^{\mu\nu}(p) = e_1 e_2\left(\int d^4 k\gamma^\mu\frac{i(\gamma^\rho k_\rho + m_1)}{k^2 - m_1^2}\gamma^\nu\frac{i(\gamma^\sigma k_\sigma + m_1)}{k^2 - m_1^2} - (1\leftrightarrow2)\right).
$$

One typically computes such diagrams in general dimension $d$ and then analytically continues to $d = 4$. However, in this special case where there are two fermions with the special charge assignments $(e_1,e_2)$ and $(e_1,-e_2)$ as in [1](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(86)91377-8), the divergences cancel, and the diagram can be computed without regularization. The result is (up to numerical factors)
$$
\Pi_{12}^{\mu\nu}(p)\sim (m_1^2 - m_2^2) g^{\mu\nu} + (p^\mu p^\nu - p^2 g^{\mu\nu})\Pi_{12}(p).
$$
This appears to violate gauge invariance. However, I think this may be because it is inconsistent to *not* use a regulator for this particular diagram, even though the result is exactly finite, since other diagrams *do* require a regulator. And indeed, if I compute $\Pi_{12}^{\mu\nu}(p)$ in general dimension $d$, then the mass term goes away, but this feels sketchy to me... Is my reasoning sensible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are evaluating two integrals of the form
$$
A\sim \int \frac{1}{k^2},\qquad B=A_{1\leftrightarrow2}
$$
In the end you are interested in $A-B$. As you correctly point out, the difference of the *integrands* is integrable, so it seems that $A-B$ requires no regularization. This is not actually correct: the two terms are individually divergent, so $A-B$ is actually an $\infty-\infty$ indeterminate.

The only way to evaluate this difference meaningfully is to regulate. Now, both integrals are convergent, and their difference is well-defined. Next, introduce couter-terms, renormalize, etc., and remove the regulator at the very end. If you do the algebra correctly, you'll see that the end-result does *not* agree with your initial, naive computation of $A-B$ where you didn't introduce a regulator.

The correct result is, happily, gauge-invariant. The incorrect result is not, but of course who cares about wrong results.